# How to automatically append query string to laravel pagination links?

Tags: laravel-4, pagination

I am working on search filter on checkbox click, with Laravel and Ajax call. So I get results when I click on a checkbox. my query is as follows:

```
$editors = User::with(['editor.credentials','editor.specialties','editor.ratings']);
$temp=$editors->whereHas('editor', function($q) use ($a_data){
    $q->whereHas('specialties',function($sq) use($a_data){
        $sq->whereIn('specialty',$a_data);
    });
})->paginate(2);
```

This gives me all the data I need. however how should I get the links for pagination?

```
$temp->setBaseUrl('editors');
$links = $temp->links()->render();
```

I am currently doing this and with $links which I am sending over as response to ajax call, I set the pagination  with $links data. Now, I need to append the query to next page like page=2?query="something". I don't know how should I go about appending the remaining query result links to next page links. i.e. I don;t know what should come in the query="something" part. Can someone guide me. thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check the answer from @Arda, as it's global solution. Below you can find how to do it manually.

Use `appends` on Paginator:

```
$querystringArray = Input::only(['search','filter','order']); // sensible examples

// or:
$querystringArray = ['queryVar' => 'something', 'anotherVar' => 'something_else'];

$temp->appends($querystringArray);
```

Answer (score 156):

```
{{ $users->appends($_GET)->links() }}
```

It will append all query string parameters into pagination link

Comment: Based on this, I used request helper in view: `{{ $users->appends(request()->query())->links() }}`

Comment: Or even better `{{ $posts->appends(request()->except('page'))->links() }}`

Comment: @FosAvance thanks.  this hadn't any value added. worked like Ehsan code for me. what is the difference??

Answer (score 64):

As of Laravel 7, you can call the `withQueryString()` method on your `Paginator` instance.

Quote from the documentation:

> If you wish to append all current query string values to the pagination links you may use the withQueryString method:
>
> ```
> {{ $users->withQueryString()->links() }}
> ```

See "Appending To Pagination Links": https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Comment: You can also apply this directly to your model query. `User::paginate()->withQueryString()` which lets you do this inside your view: `{{ $users->links() }}`

Comment: Thanks bro this is the best solution.

Comment: Laravel 10 docs no longer show this method of doing it, however it **does work** _with the current version 10_.

Answer (score 19):

For the latest version of Laravel at the moment (5.2), you can just use the Request facade to retrieve the query string and pass that to your paginator's appends() method

```
$input = Request::input();
$myModelsPaginator = App\Models\MyModel::paginate();
$myModelsPaginator->appends($input);
```

Answer (score 19):

Append all input except the actual page, form token and what you don't want to pass:

```
$paginatedCollection->appends($request->except(['page','_token']));
```

Answer (score 16):

Add this anywhere in your app (e.g routes.php, filters.php or anything that's autoloaded), no need to edit any pagination codes that is written already. This works flawlessly using view composers, and you don't need to know any query string parameters:

```
////////PAGINATION QUERY STRING APPEND
View::composer(Paginator::getViewName(), function($view) {
    $queryString = array_except(Input::query(), Paginator::getPageName());
    $view->paginator->appends($queryString);
});
//////////////////
```

Comment: FatalErrorException in routes.php line 20: Class 'Paginator' not found

Comment: This Answer is for Laravel 4 @Tarzan, In Laravel 5, classes are PSR-4 standards, so you need to add \ character before. But I've not tried this in LAravel 5.

Comment: View::composer(\Paginator::getViewName(), function($view) {
   $queryString = array_except(Input::query(), \Paginator::getPageName());
   $view->paginator->appends($queryString);
}); not working

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using ? @Tarzan

Comment: Laravel 5, Can u suggest me how i get http://localhost/search/Filipino Filipino in my controller, want a filter according to filipino

Comment: In Laravel 5 class `Paginator` don't have `getViewName()` method. This solution is only for Laravel 4.

Answer (score 15):

Inspired from previous answers I ended up using the service container for both frontend + api support.

In your `AppServiceProvider@boot()` method:

```
$this->app->resolving(LengthAwarePaginator::class, function ($paginator) {
    return $paginator->appends(array_except(Input::query(), $paginator->getPageName()));
});
```

Comment: worth notting, that you better bind both paginator types, lenghaware and normal

Comment: this helped me solve my problem. I added a new answer for Laravel 8

Answer (score 13):

you can used request helper in view as same

```
{{ $users->appends(request()->query())->links() }}
```

Comment: Perfect Answer. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

in your view where you display pagination...

```
{{ $results->appends(Request::except('page'))->links() }}
```

appends keeps the query string value except "page". not sure if it will work with POST request

Answer (score 3):

```
  {{ $users->appends(Request::only(['filter','search']))->links()}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 10 can use **withQueryString**

Example: `$users = User::paginate(15)->withQueryString();`

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#appending-query-string-values

Or, when displaying the links using the helper method, however it appears that method is not documented any more (not that I could find using the search bar in their docs).

`$users->withQueryString()->links()`

Answer (score 2):

### Updating @rasmus answer for Laravel 8.

In your AppServiceProvider boot method, add the following lines and your existing query string will be be used for all pagination links

```
$this->app->resolving(Paginator::class, function ($paginator) {
    return $paginator->appends(Arr::except(Request::query(), $paginator->getPageName()));
});
$this->app->resolving(LengthAwarePaginator::class, function ($paginator) {
    return $paginator->appends(Arr::except(Request::query(), $paginator->getPageName()));
});
```

And for completeness, use these classes:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

Comment: 2022 This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

From Laravel 8 use add 'withQueryString()' to paginate:

```
$users = User::paginate(15)->withQueryString();
```

Documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination)

Answer (score 0):

**$this->app->resolving(LengthAwarePaginator::class, function ($paginator) {
return $paginator->appends(Arr::except(Request::query(), $paginator->getPageName()));
});**

Add the following line to the AppServiceProvider.php file to include the query string in all paginations across the application. Make sure to import classes.