# Laravel 5.5 manual pagination add URL parameters and query strings

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm implementing manual pagination using the LenghtAwarePagination class and it works but when I use:

```
{{ $result->links() }}
```

in the `search` view, it generates the links without taking the current URL into account. Like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/?page=2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/?page=3">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="/?page=4">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, the URL is like this:

```
mypage.com/search/63.231237/12.4491092/?filter=true&filter2=true
```

I think it would be too much trouble to append each parameter one by one to the pagination links so how can I take whatever is after `mypage.com`, in this case this:

```
/search/63.231237/12.4491092/?filter=true&filter2=true
```

. So I need to replace this:

```
/
/?page=2 
/?page=3
/?page=4
```

for this:

```
/search/63.231237/12.4491092/?filter=true&filter2=true
/search/63.231237/12.4491092/?filter=true&filter2=true&page=2
/search/63.231237/12.4491092/?filter=true&filter2=true&page=3
/search/63.231237/12.4491092/?filter=true&filter2=true&page=4
```

How can I do it from within the links function?

**EDIT: I got it to work using this:**

```
$currentURL = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$result= $this->paginate($results)->withPath($currentURL);
```

But there's a problem, I need to strip `page=x` out of `$currentURL`, how can I do that?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41976594

Comment: For the first problem you can use laravel helpers to get the current url in the view like this `url()->current()` for the second one you can use php's strtok function like this `$currentURL = strtok($currentURL, '&').strtok('&');` :)